# how to send email from my app in facebook

Tags: java, facebook, email

In writing an app for Facebook using Java, I need to send a message to my users.  The app will send the email when something happens.

How can you send an email in a Java Facebook application?

Answer (score 1):

I've never developed a Facebook app -- but, assuming you know how to write a basic Java Facebook app and that you just aren't sure about how to send emails, try this: http://commons.apache.org/email/

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking first how to get the facebook user's email address. If that is the case you need to request the "email" extended permission when your user authenticates your application. After that just use a standard smtp client to send mail using your SMTP email server. You can find some documentation on that here: http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html